# How to print a larger version of the fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the following code to print my canvas and was wondering if it is possible to do something like `toDataURL({multiplier: 4})`? I plugged it in but can't actually see a different anywhere. Not sure if it's worth having this in or if there's a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

```
function printCanvas() {
var dataUrl = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL(/* data multiplier here? */); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
  var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  windowContent += '<html>'
  windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
  windowContent += '<body>'
  windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
  windowContent += '</body>';
  windowContent += '</html>';
  var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(windowContent);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw multiplier does not seems to be working, I tired changing the width and height of image element which we going to print was able to scale the image, may be this will help you.  ex. windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close(); style="widht:1100px;height:1200px;">

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a new canvas which is scaled as per your need and draw the original canvas contents there and then use the new canvas's `toDataURL()` to create the image.

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
        var tempCanvas;
        var tempCanvasCtx;

        function printCanvas() {
            var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            tempCanvas.height = canvas.height;
            tempCanvasCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
            tempCanvasCtx.scale(1.5, 1.5);
            tempCanvasCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
            var dataUrl = tempCanvas.toDataURL(); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
            var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
            windowContent += '<html>'
            windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
            windowContent += '<body>'
            windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
            windowContent += '</body>';
            windowContent += '</html>';
            var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
            printWin.document.open();
            printWin.document.write(windowContent);
        }
```